# Query to list %process% metrics in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm creating a new dashboard in Grafana for a list of VM processes. I want to view metrics for a range of processes that start from a specific letter or abbreviation. Is there any way to query the process as LIKE not only equal in Grafana?

Let's say I want to get metrics from all processes which have the word 'java', for instance.

```
0 + (avg by (process) (rate(wmi_process_cpu_time_total{process="java"}[5m])) * 100)
```

Can I have something like: {process LIKE %java%}.
Thank you for help!

P.S. I'm using Grafana + Prometheus + wmi_exporter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
{process=~".*java.*"}
```

See more info in the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/)